# Book recommendation for undergraduate stats with Mathematica

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references, mathematica

Having just completed my Bachelor with a major in math and physics, I am aware that due to my chosen specialisation, I lack a good training and exposure in statistics beyond the first year.

Could anyone recommend a good book on statistics where the author uses Wolfram Mathematica as a computational tool?

Comment: Statistics is a big field. Can you narrow down what specifically you are interested in?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Undergraduate statistic

Comment: "Undergrad statistics" can be mathematical statistics, time series analysis and forecasting, classification, actuarial statistics, analysis of experiments, analysis of clinical trials or a host of other things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For many examples showing the power of *Mathematica* to perform statistical calculations, see *Mathematical Statistics with Mathematica* by Colin Rose and Murray D. Smith.

[image: Book cover]

Rose is active on this site, answering (at this point) over 100 questions with code and illustrations generated with the associated software, [*MathStatica*.](http://www.mathstatica.com/book/)  You can find links to them through [his CV user profile](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/24905/wolfies).

Answer (score 2):

There are not too many books of that sort.

One that looks nice (for mathematical statistics) is [https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Statistics-Mathematica-Springer-Texts/dp/0387952349/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1511959110&sr=1-2&keywords=mathematica++statistics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387952349) which should fit your background in math and physics.

Another one, more oriented to practical data analysis is [https://www.amazon.com/Statistics-Mathematica-Martha-L-Abell/dp/0120415542/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1511959110&sr=1-1&keywords=mathematica++statistics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0120415542)  .

There seems to be very little overlap between the two.